# tracking all consumers for WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have standard enterprise level WEB Api , which is going to be used across the organisation. I can have demarcation like Mainframe Systems/Online channel/etc through API key.

However there can be many systems( say many systems in online)  in WEBAPI that can share the same key. I need to identify each and every call uniquely and if it is not being shared

any ways for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could just log the IP address of each request. If all the systems are internal to your organisation then it shouldn't be hard to match IPs to what system it is.

**Edit**

Or you could pass a client Id as well as the API Key.

Comment: Well problem is most of it would be originating from the same IP  so that solution is out , and dev in multiple team can pass the same client id.